# uso del tag # en formularios Angular

Tags: html, angular

Estaba estudiando este pedacito de código.

```
<label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.name" required />
    <span class="form_error" *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
        El nombre es obligatorio
    </span>
```

no entiendo cual es la funcion del `#name="ngModel"` exactamente, para que se usa, y cual es la diferencia con el `name="name"` ?

Comment: Con # en angular obtienes la referencia del elemento.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables